# Is the integration of Dirac delta function and another function correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, dirac-delta

I have the first derivative of a function, and I want to solve the original function through its indefinite integral.
$$
\frac{d\phi}{dx}=\left[ \frac{1}{\left( EI \right) _0}+\sum_{i=1}^N{\frac{1}{k_i}\delta \left( x-x_i \right)} \right] g\left( x \right) 
$$
But the answer I saw was different from the result I solved. I'm not sure if this is because of the series.

This is the answer I saw.
$$
\phi \left( x \right) =\frac{g^1\left( x \right)}{\left( EI \right) _0}+\sum_{i=1}^N{\frac{g\left( x_i \right)}{k_i}H\left( x-x_i \right)}+C_1
$$
where,
$$
g^1\left( x \right) =\int{g\left( x \right) dx}
$$
The integral rule of Dirac delta function I found is this：
$$
\int{f\left( x \right) \delta \left( x-x_0 \right) dx\ =}f\left( x_0 \right) 
$$
Therefore, I think there is no step function in the solution：
$$
\phi \left( x \right) =\frac{g^1\left( x \right)}{\left( EI \right) _0}+\sum_{i=1}^N{\frac{g\left( x_i \right)}{k_i}}+C_1
$$
This confuses me. Please tell me that the result is correct, thank you.

Comment: Write out the indefinite integral as a definite integral from $0$ to $x$ and the step functions come from the usual definition, which should be a definite integral as well.

Comment: @whpowell96 I see what you mean. If the form of definite integral is adopted, the result should have a step function. If the indefinite integral form is adopted, the result will have no step function.

Comment: I do not know of any definition of the indefinite integral of a delta function that does not involve a step function.

Comment: The rule that you found for the Dirac delta is indeed about its integral on the whole space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g\in C_C^\infty$ and $\phi$ be a distribution such that $\phi'$ is given by

$$\phi'(x)=g(x)\left(\frac1{(EI)_0}+\sum_{i=1}^N\frac1{k_i}\delta(x-x_i)\right)$$

Then, we have for any $\psi\in C^\infty_C$

$$\begin{align}
\langle \phi',\psi\rangle&=\frac1{(EI)_0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\psi(x)\,dx+\sum_{i=1}^N \frac1{k_i}g(x_i)\psi(x_i)\\\\
&=-\langle \phi,\psi'\rangle
\end{align}$$

Then, $\phi$ is the distribution given by

$$\phi(x)=\frac1{(EI)_0}\int_{-\infty}^x g(t)\,dt+\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1{k_i}g(x_i)H(x-x_i)+C$$

for a constant $C$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x>0$ and $x_i>0$
, the result of definite integral form is that:
$$
\int_0^x{f\left( x \right) \delta \left( x-x_i \right) =f\left( x_i \right) H\left( x-x_i \right)}
$$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The Dirac Delta is not a function, it is a distribution that operates on test functions.